# What permissions are required for the Win32 LogonUser function?

Tags: winapi, authentication

Suppose that I want to run the LogonUser function in my code for a user with uid Bob, what permissions must Bob have for me to be able to call this function to log in as Bob successfully?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a list anywhere since parts of the security system can use custom "plugins" ([Authentication Packages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374733%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [Security Support Provider Interface/Security packages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374731%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#sspi_functions) and [GINA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_Identification_and_Authentication)/[Credential Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx)) and they might have other requirements.

On a default system it probably goes something like this:

- The named user account passed to LogonUser needs the [SE_*_LOGON_NAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb545671%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) account right that matches the logon type (LOGON32_LOGON_*) and the logon needs to pass the LSA and/or domain controller requirements (Logon hours, password not expired etc)
- The process calling LogonUser needs SE_CHANGE_NOTIFY_NAME (Everyone has this by default), maybe SE_TCB_NAME (Required on Win2000). If you are going to call CreateProcessAsUser on the returned token you also need SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME and maybe SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME...

If you just want to start a process as another user you might want to use [CreateProcessWithLogonW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), if you just want to validate the credentials [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180548) has a code example that does not use LogonUser (It seems like it might have some guest account issues though)